# Figuring out the right SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

I am trying to somehow find all the owl:sameAs properties from a resource link. A simple query would be like

```
SELECT ?x WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tetris>  owl:sameAs ?x
}
```

However i also would like to get the Yago link mentioned as is owl:sameAs  of. Could any one help me out how to do this ?

Comment: "link mentioned as is owl:sameAs  of" does not make sense to me.  Please update your post

Answer (score 3):

You can get the YAGO link like so:

```
SELECT ?x WHERE {
  ?x owl:sameAs <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tetris>
}
```

Or get both the “incoming” and “outgoing” links in one query:

```
SELECT ?x WHERE {
  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tetris>  owl:sameAs ?x }
  UNION
  { ?x owl:sameAs <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tetris> }
}
```